# Get tile position on what a mouse clicked

Tags: java, swing, chess

I am writing a chess game using Java and Swing, And I wanted to get the tile position on which a mouse clicked. I searched through internet, but all of them were really off, and never accurate. When I clicked on a tile's first half, it said it was tile 1, but on the second half, it said it was tile 2, but it was still tile 1. So I was wondering, how can I do it?

My tile size is (75, 75)
This is the code I've written for tileX: `Math.floor((double)evt.getX() / 75)`, and this is the code I've written for tileY: `Math.floor((double)evt.getY() / 75)`.

Comment: If you don't tell us how your system works, what you've tried, or precisely how they were "off", then we're likely to end up giving you one of the solutions that's already out there that isn't working for you. Please edit your question to walk us through how you've implemented it so far, and give us a precise reproducible test case so we know exactly what offset we need to correct for.

Comment: In future, please edit your existing question instead of posting a duplicate.